# Slither.io Logo Animation

Tags: animation, canvas

I'm new to canvas animations and I'm trying to find out how to make an elegant logo animation like the one on [Slither.io](http://slither.io/).

My research has shown me how to do simple animations, but can someone direct me on how to do something like Slither? Also, is this text being animated, or is it a graphic?

I'm very much a beginner and I'm just struggling on how to get started on working with animations like the slither logo. All the tutorials out there are very basic and i have not found anything with a real world application applied to it.

thanks for any help/direction.

Comment: It uses a 2D canvas. Here is [one way to make a wavy effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586754/how-can-i-recreate-this-wavy-image-effect/29591859#29591859) on 2D canvas. But your question seem to be off-topic as it stands now.

Comment: That looks like it is done by rendering the words with a gradient, then getting the pixel data with ctx.getImageData then moving the pixels to a second pixel array width a transform of some type.